# Tumblr, get the current tag of the /tagged/nameoftag page

Tags: tumblr

I am making a HTML theme but I need to grab the currently viewed tag, is this possible?

I tried {Tag} but it doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentURL = document.URL;
    currentURL = currentURL.substring(currentURL.indexOf("tagged") + 7);    
    console.log('current', currentURL);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the tag variable within the tag block

```
{block:TagPage}
{Tag}
{/block:TagPage}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me!